# What does it means when a React Functional Component returns an JSX.IntrinsicElements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I found this react functional component in [some documentation](https://binarapps.com/integrate-fabric-js-canvas-drawing-library-with-react-app-via-uncontrolled-component/)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

interface ITextProps {
  id: string;
  options: fabric.ITextboxOptions;
  canvas: fabric.Canvas;
  onChange: (id: string, options: fabric.ITextboxOptions) => void;
}
export function Text({ onChange, id, canvas, options }: ITextProps) {
  const [textbox] = useState<fabric.Textbox>(() => new fabric.Textbox(options.text ?? '', options));

  useEffect(() => {
    canvas.add(textbox);
  }, [canvas, textbox]);

  useEffect(() => {
    textbox.setOptions(options);
  }, [options, textbox]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const update = () => {
      onChange(id, textbox.toObject());
    };
    textbox.on('moved', update);
    textbox.on('scaled', update);
    textbox.on('rotated', update);
    textbox.on('changed', update);
  }, [id, onChange, textbox]);

  return <></>;
}
```

At first i didn't understand what is that returned jsx by that function but when i tried add a className to the returned <></> , i got the error

> Property 'className' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

All i could find as documentation about Intrinsic elements was [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#intrinsic-elements) but i didn't see there an example where only empty brackets like that.

I also thought that could be a typescript shorthand for  but i'm not sure about this
what does it mean to return <></> ?

Comment: <></> is called react fragments https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: `<></>` is React.Fragment type

Comment: You should put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys
it's actually a shorthand for react's Fragment i didn't know https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax